# Extract data from conditional effect

Tags: r, plot, extract, bayesian, brms

I'm using R and I would like to extract data from conditional effect

```
rb15 <- brm(X ~ 1 + Y , data = CB, family=sratio("logit"), cores = 4)
amc <- conditional_effects(rb15, categorical = TRUE)
```

[image: plot from amc]

I would like it to be in a data frame with row like X,Y and Probability

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I can't verify the code without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but a summary data frame is available in the `amc` object like so:

```
amc <- conditional_effects(rb15, categorical = TRUE)
amc_data <- amc[[1]]
```